# Heat and Meditation

Tags: meditation-practicalities

I was meditating and couldn't keep my eyes open. I wore a thick sweater, and when I removed this sweater, the lethargy dissipated and instead I faced distracted thoughts, but I meditated with much more alertness.

**Is temperature a factor at all in meditation?**

Answer (score 1):

I say Yes, ...but how can we find out?

Temperature gives a great opportunity to develop the patience paramis, for the benefit of one and all, so we can reach enlightenment. Further, we can observe the warming effects of temperature sensations, by environment or hot sauce and garlic. Some meditators have renounced garlic and Habeñeros because of the phycho sematic effects. I have observed one overcome with heat, feeling like a whiney puppy, with the red rocket out desperate and agitated. Full of madness and siracha. The one was me. However, a hot environment is an opportunity to develop tolerance and patience, so when in varied temperatures we can remain balanced.  Also, intermittent fasting can greatly reduced heat accumulated in the body and agitation in the mind.  The study ofAyurveda offers many insights into how heat may affect us